# WP Admin is locked with error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_wp_version_compatible()

Tags: wordpress, git, plugins, conflict

I just started managing a Wordpress site created in Genesis. The host uses version control on GitHub. On the local site, the Enable JQuery Monitor and JQuery Migrate Helper plugins were deactivated. They are activated on the Master. I just pushed some updated plugins (no conflict in staging) and I got an error message on the Master. The backend is now locked. I don't fully understand the error message. Any help or ideas are appreciated.

````
 ``` Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_wp_version_compatible()
    in /home/apfunders/webapps/funders_production/wp-content/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate- 
    helper/templates/admin-notices/no-longer-needed.php on line 26 

    Call stack:

     include_once()
     wp-content/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/class-jquery-migrate-helper.php:542
     jQuery_Migrate_Helper::plugin_obsolete_message()
     wp-content/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/class-jquery-migrate-helper.php:552
     jQuery_Migrate_Helper::admin_notices()
     wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:286
     WP_Hook::apply_filters()
     wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310
     WP_Hook::do_action()
     wp-includes/plugin.php:453
     do_action()
     wp-admin/admin-header.php:255
     require_once()
     wp-admin/admin.php:216
     require_once()
     wp-admin/tools.php:10
````

Comment: Please read the tag information for the tags you used. What does the [tag:conflict] tag say about when to use the tag, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to disable the plug-in "enable-jquery-migrate-helper". Try to go in your cPanel or FTP of your Server and search in the Wordpress folder > plugin > "enable-jquery-migrate-helper" and try to rename it with something else like:"enable-jquery-migrate-helper-old", save and check if the site is working. As it seems your version of wordpress isnt compatible with that plugin